# Placing Books on Shelves Permutation Question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**Question:** There are five distinct A, three distinct B
books, and two distinct C books. In how many ways can these
books be arranged on a shelf if one of the B books is on the
left of all A books, and another B book is on
the right of all the A books?

This is what I've done:

**Step 1:** Place all A books first so, 5!

**Step 2:** Place B books

3 choose 2 ways to place B books + 4 ways to place the remaining B book

**Step 3:** Place C books

5 choose 2 ways to place C books

Is this the correct way to approach this question? I got 24000 ways as an answer.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Choose an order for the A books . . . . . $5!$ ways
- Choose the leftmost B book . . . . . $3$ ways
- Choose the rightmost B book . . . . . $2$ ways
- At this stage we have B A A A A A B.  Choose one of the spaces to take the last B book . . . . . $6$ ways.
- We have now a row of $8$ books; choose a place for the first (e.g., in alphabetical order) of the C books . . . . . $9$ ways.
- Choose a place for the other C book . . . . .$10$ ways.

Answer: $5!\times3\times2\times6\times10\times9=388800$.

---

**Comment**.  It is important to always be clear on **what** you are choosing.  For example, when you say "$5$ choose $2$ ways to place C books", this would mean you are choosing $2$ somethings from $5$ possible somethings.  I don't what are the "somethings" you are choosing.  What you should be choosing are two **places** for the books, and at this stage there are $9$ places available, not $5$.

Comment: How come there are 6 ways to place the last B book? I count 8 spaces including the ends.

Comment: At this stage we have the following arrangement, with spaces clearly marked: BSASASASASASB.  The "spaces at the ends" are not available because in steps 2 and 3 we specifically chose the **leftmost** and **rightmost** B books.